# ansible not finding roles when installed using pipenv

Tags: ansible, virtualenv, pipenv

I have been looking at different ways to test [ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible) playbooks and came across this blog post by [Jeff Geerling](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/testing-ansible-roles-travis-ci-github).

Replicating his exact example works, however, when I replicate it but managing python (and ansible) via a pipenv install I get the following error

```
ERROR! the role 'ansible-test' was not found in /Users/philip/Desktop/ansible-test/tests/roles:/Users/philip/ansible-test:/Users/philip/Desktop/ansible-test/tests

The error appears to have been in '/Users/philip/Desktop/ansible-test/tests/test.yml': line 4, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  roles:
    - ansible-test
      ^ here
```

The content of `test.yml` is

```
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: root
  roles:
    - ansible-test
```

which passes [yamllint](http://www.yamllint.com/) fine.

`ansible.cfg` contains

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ../../ansible-test
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with being in a Virtualenv, but can't explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role**s** path is the path for all role**s**.

Ansible searches for a directory with the name of the role in the `roles_path`. If the role is called `ansible-test`, it is an error to put the name of the role into the `roles_path`.

Set `roles_path` this way:

```
[defaults]
roles_path = ../..
```

And make sure, that you are in the right directory, when you call `ansible-playbook`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the explanation!